# how to make onclick remove to an item dynamacly created listview Android

Tags: android

I am working on an app that requires removing items from a ListView on a button event.
i tried to remove the item with removeView method but it's not working

can someone help me to make onclick in the listview to remove the item when a bottun is clicked

here is my code :

```
package com.example.debt;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class debt_page extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    Button buttonAdd;
    ArrayList<debt_data> data = new ArrayList<>();
    View cricketerView;
    Button deletebt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dept_page);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_items);
        buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.button);

        View cricketerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_list,null,false);
        deletebt = (Button) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button) ;

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.button:

                addView();

                break;



        }


    }


    private void addView() {



//        EditText editText = (EditText)cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.edit_cricketer_name);
//        AppCompatSpinner spinnerTeam = (AppCompatSpinner)cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_team);
//        ImageView imageClose = (ImageView)cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.image_remove);


        // get the  name input from user
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        // get the  amount of money input from user
        EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        String amount1 = amount.getText().toString();
        //get the  note input from user
        EditText notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes);


//        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,teamList);
//        spinnerTeam.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dataList_adapter adapter;
        adapter = new dataList_adapter(this, R.layout.adapter_list, data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        View cricketerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_list,null,false);
        deletebt = (Button) cricketerView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button) ;


        //check if the input is not empty
        String str_name = name.getText().toString();
        double finalValue = Integer.parseInt(amount1);
        String str_notes = notes.getText().toString();
        if (!(name.getText() == null || name.getText().equals("") || amount1.equals("") || notes.getText() == null || notes.getText().equals(""))) {
            data.add(new debt_data(str_name, finalValue, str_notes));
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            name.getText().clear();
            amount.getText().clear();
            notes.getText().clear();
            //            listView.addView(dataArray);
            deletebt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    removeView(cricketerView);
                }
            });

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            listView.addView(cricketerView);
        }



    }

    private void removeView(View view){
        listView.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

and this is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DAD5D5"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutParent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:text="المبلغ"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.664"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:text="الاسم"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.786"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/group2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="بحث"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.896"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="ملاحظات"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
        android:text="ملاحظات"
        android:layout_marginStart="156dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="156dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="الاسم"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="صفحة الدين"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="المبلغ"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView10" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--    TODO : اربط المعلومات مع اللست فيو -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:background="#F3EBEB"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.447"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="248dp"
        android:background="#F3EBEB"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="انقر للبحث"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.567"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#F3EBEB"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/amount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/amount" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#F3EBEB"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name" />

    <!--TODO:  ضيف زر للحذف سطر محدد و نافذة تاكيد للحذف تحتوي خيار نعم و خيار لا-->


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="اضافة"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notes" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="286dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

i tried to use notifyItemRemoved and it doesn't work either
i wish someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an item on button click then you should follow these steps

1- remove the item from list like

JAVA

`list.remove(item);` or `list.removeAt(position);`

Kotlin

`list.remove(item)` or `list.removeAt(position)`

2- renew the list by passing updated list to adapter and replacing old list

```
kotlin

adapter.renewList(updatedList)

JAVA

adapter.renewList(updatedList);
```

in adapter

```
kotlin

fun renewList(list:ArrayList<Item>){
    this.list = list
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

JAVA

```
public void renewList(ArrayList<Item> list){
        this.list=list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

That's all you need to do it.

Comment: what is the java code for it I tried a similar method removeView()  but it didn't work

Comment: @luckiwish added java code also and you should create separate/Custom adapter class and then try above steps.

Comment: thank you and  i changed to using recyclerview and it worked